# Convergence of matrix exponential for infinite-dimensional operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that the matrix exponential always converges for finite-dimensional matrices, but on page 146 of Principles of Quantum Mechanics (Shankar), it says that the exponential series $e^{-iH}$ does not always converge, where $H$ is a Hermitian operator. Can anyone suggest an example of this failure to converge, and what conditions can be tested to prove convergence?

Comment: For a bounded operator, this always converges, so I guess the problem is that H could be unbounded...